# Angular ContentChild with template reference to 3rd party components

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm venturing into new territory in my Angular development (both code and knowledge).  I've not really used Content/View/Child/Children functionality.  In developing my first directive, I have been thrust into another level.  I am approaching this problem in baby steps.

I am trying to write my unit tests and seem to not correctly use ContentChild.  To test a directive I have created a simple component.  I am going to try to first understand an issue with that simple component.  I am trying to get the underlying PrimeNG component by ContentChild.  I am using template reference to identify the PrimeNG's dropdown component, but it seems to fail to do that, because it is undefined in the after-content-init life-cycle hook.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ContentChild, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Dropdown } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<p-dropdown #pDD [options]='cities'
    [disabled]='ddDisabled'
    [(ngModel)]='selectedCity'>
</p-dropdown>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit { 
    cities: SelectItem[];
    selectedCity: string;
    ddDisabled: boolean = true;
    @ContentChild( 'pDD' ) contentDD: Dropdown;
    @ViewChild( 'pDD' ) viewDD: Dropdown;
    constructor() {
        this.cities = [
            {label: 'New York', value: 'NY'},
            {label: 'Rome', value: 'RM'},
            {label: 'London', value: 'LDN'},
            {label: 'Istanbul', value: 'IST'},
            {label: 'Paris', value: 'PRS'}
        ];
        this.selectedCity = 'LDN';
    }
    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        console.warn( 'Content:', this.contentDD );
        console.warn( 'View:', this.viewDD );
    }
}
```

What am I not understanding and how do I get the component reference (not element reference)?

Demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-content-view-child?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: template is called `View` in angular, so the correct hook would be `ngAfterViewInit`. content stands for content projection via `ng-content`

Comment: These are 3rd party controls.  The source for Dropdown control is here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts  It uses a lot of ng-container, but no ng-content.  But, FYI, I have the same problem with @ViewChild.  ngAfterContentInit happens after ngAfterViewInit, so both view and content should be rendered.

Comment: true, but in particularlyyour example @ViewChild and ngAfterViewInit is a right way